# MVC2 SelectedListItem not binding to ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, viewmodel, selectlistitem

I am having a problem with a selectlistitem, the values of which are being retrieved from a database.

It is displaying the list of items in the view, but it is not passing through (POSTing) the selected value into the model.

So when the user submits, or the page reloads due to validation, the select value (PositionApplied) is empty.

Can anyone give me some pointers as to where I am going wrong?

**In my controller:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        PopulateJobsDropdown();
        return View();
    }

    private void PopulateJobsDropdown()
    {
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = _service.GetJobs()
            .Select(c => new SelectListItem
                             {
                                 Value = c.JobID.ToString(),
                                 Text = c.JobTitle
                             });
        ViewData["PositionApplied"] = items;
    }
```

**In my ViewModel**

```
 public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PositionApplied { get; set; }
```

**In my View**

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("PositionApplied")%>
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, where is the code line that get's the

```
ViewData["PositionApplied"] = items;
```

into

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PositionApplied { get; set; }
```

something like:

```
this.PositionApplied = ViewData["PositionApplied"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>;
```

and you can simple use in your View:

```
<%
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PositionApplied = 
          ViewData["PositionApplied"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>;
%>
```

...

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("myDropDOwnId", PositionApplied) %>
```

or is there some of automagical happening under MVC2 that I'm not aware about? As I use the example I give you, all the time.

---

**Added**

in order to avoid Linq to Entities error (if you are using it) change your method to

```
private void PopulateJobsDropdown()
{
    IQueryble<Your_Table> jobs = _service.GetJobs();
    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach(var job in jobs)
        items.add(new SelectListItem
                      {
                         Value = c.JobID.ToString(),
                         Text = c.JobTitle
                      });
    ViewData["PositionApplied"] = items;
}
```

and all will work fine.

Comment: I've tried that and the model is still null - the value is not being passed through.. What am I missing??

Comment: debug and see what `PositionApplied` variable have as well `ViewData["PositionApplied"]` in the controller and when you get to the View

Comment: I'm almost sure that you will end up smashing into the `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression` problem...

Comment: Nope still doesn't work. The select list value is not being passed into the model.Tried all the examples here. So frustrating :(

Comment: Also I can't add this is the viewModel as it causes problems

:public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PositionApplied { get; set; }

Comment: works fine on my end, so, it's something you are doing wrong that is not this part of the code. Could be your `_service.GetJobs()`